# splitter does not return results if the xml namespace:prefix is not present in the input xml

Tags: mule, mule-component, dataweave

```
 <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/order" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <splitter expression="#[xpath3('//elements/element',payload,'NODESET')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
```

My input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<elements xmlns="http://xxx/xxservice">

    <element>
        <date>2015-09-03T14:30:36.000Z</order-date>
        <created-by>user1</created-by>

    </element>

      <element>
        <date>2015-09-04T14:30:36.000Z</order-date>
        <created-by>user2</created-by>

    </element>

</elements>
```

This does not return any results. If i change the input xml to below, splitter is returning resutls

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<elements xmlns:a="http://xxx/xxservice">

    <element>
        <date>2015-09-03T14:30:36.000Z</order-date>
        <created-by>user1</created-by>

    </element>

      <element>
        <date>2015-09-04T14:30:36.000Z</order-date>
        <created-by>storefront2</created-by>

    </element>

</elements>
```

Please note only thing i changed is xmlns to xmlns:a in the `<elements xmlns="http://xxx/xxservice">`

What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely due to the namespace issue. If you have an enterprise licence you can raise a ticket to Mule support

Alternatively what you can do is try skipping namespace dynamically in ***XPATH3*** and can use `mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer` in the following to extract the xml elements values:-

```
 <splitter expression="#[xpath3('/*:elements/*:element',payload,'NODESET')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
 <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
 <logger message="created-by: #[xpath3('/*:element/*:created-by',payload,'STRING')]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
 <logger message="date: #[xpath3('/*:element/*:date',payload,'STRING')]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

The above expression will work for **both** the ***namespaces*** you provided here and you can get the xml element values without any issues and the splitter will not complain